# Sending FCM Push notification at 2 different event

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to implement FCM push notification at multiple event through **node.js** . i.e I want to send notification

1. when someone sends a message.
2. When someone comment on a post.

I am able to receive notification on single event ( on sending message ) What would i have to do in order to receive notification at both events ? Either i have to add two different files ? 
I have no idea any help will be appreciated ..Thank you

Comment: add another `onWrite()` so when someone comments it will trigger and you can send a notification

Comment: Adding second onWrite() outside first onWrite() ?

Comment: Like [this](https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/48f50df6884708625b4dbdb383bf9bb8) ??

Comment: yes like that..

Comment: @Peter its not working Sir .. When I do so only second OnWrite() is being called on data change ... First onWrite() is never being called

Comment: check if the location is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168793/discussion-between-nabeel-kamboh-and-peter-haddad).

Comment: @PeterHaddad ??

Comment: add the code here in the question and explain why it is not working

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/48f50df6884708625b4dbdb383bf9bb8), there are 2 onWrite() functions suppose first one is **a** and second is **B** , I checked both functions are working if i write only one onWrite() function, but if there are 2 fucntions only the second onwrite() is being called (**B**) even if i am trying to call first one (**A**) but if i replaced their positions ( i.e B as a frst function and A as second ) then **A** is being called ....
Sorry for poor english ... i hope i conveyed my point

Comment: the onWrite() will only trigger when you add data to the database at the specified location

Comment: thats what i am trying to say, i am adding data to database but it never triggerss ..

Comment: I want to send push notification when someone sends me a message nd second when anyone comment on my post .. Actually when i write one onwrite() function either it is of chat onwrite() or function that should trigger on comment, they are working but if i write both functions at a time in one file, only function that is written at second number is triggered ( Assume i write chat notification's onwrite() function at second place) so on sending a message other person receieves notification , but if i comment on a post, comment's on write() is not being triggered ( because it is on first place )

Comment: Kindly help me out sir ? @PeterHaddad

Comment: I don't know what the problem is